# SqlParameter vs array of object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has many parameters and I've been using the following to return the results:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<GetListCamera_Result>("Camera.sp_get_list_camera @room_name, @disk_status, 
    @signal_loss_reason, @department_id , @sortColumnName, @sortDirection, @start, @length",
                    new SqlParameter("room_name", room_name),
                    new SqlParameter("disk_status", disk_status),
                    new SqlParameter("department_id", department),
                    new SqlParameter("signal_loss_reason", reason),
                    new SqlParameter("sortColumnName", sortColumnName),
                    new SqlParameter("sortDirection", sortDirection),
                    new SqlParameter("start", start),
                    new SqlParameter("length", length)).ToList();
```

I saw one of my senior using these much more cleaner than mine:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<GetLiquidbooks_Result>("sp_get_liquidbooks {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}",
    new object[] { LiquidCode, LibID, LocPrefix, LocID, UserID }).ToList();
```

What are the differences and is there anything I need to be aware of if I'm switching to his

Answer (score 1):

I think yours is a much safer way. However, if you'd like to make it simpler, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql#loading-entities-from-stored-procedures), you don't have to initialize a `SqlParameter` instance, but the `@p1 @p2` syntax is still essential. In the first section of the article, it also mentions that this care should be taken.

AFAIK, SqlQuery doesn't prevent SQL Injection, which means if I pass the `DROP` command into your second sample, the table may be deleted permanently. Therefore, the one which the senior wrote might expose potential security risks, you should make sure that you use parameters in your query in the correct way to guard against such attacks.

About the second sample, consider using `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>()`, it allows you to pass the query string with `{0} {1}` syntax and object array as the parameter into the method. This method actually invokes `CreateStoreCommand` which transforms your query and objects into a parameterized query. But SqlQuery seems not.

---

FYI:

- [ExecuteStoreQuery source code](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/02104044fae2aca5d3a1f50f55f4af940a3c64a8/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ObjectContext.cs) - You can take a look at this method to get deep into how it works.
- [SqlQuery source code](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/02104044fae2aca5d3a1f50f55f4af940a3c64a8/src/EntityFramework/Database.cs) - As aforementioned, I rechecked the source code, and I couldn't find any codes that help to turn it into parameterized SQL